# Import PFX Certificate into separate CurrentUser - Personal store (PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, certificate

I've been wrapping my head around automating a way to perform this task:

We deploy Windows Server 2008 R2 images for our customers. We use PowerShell (version 2) to deploy our proprietary software and make various other changes to the system before shipping. This PowerShell process is run under the local Administrator account until it finishes and disables the local Administrator account.

Now, to the issue - I'm trying to install a .PFX client certificate to a SEPARATE user's CurrentUser\My certificate store. Let's call that user "SQL".

Right now the certificate is getting installed under the LocalMachine\My certificate store but one of our development teams have concerns on that position and would like to replicate the original setup.

Now, I know how to get this done dirty by adding in a reboot-step to our deployment script and having this performed under the "SQL" user but I would like to avoid that as it seems like there has to be a way to get this done while under another account. Here's the basic code we're using now to install the certificate to the LocalMachine\My store. Assume $certPath is the path to the .pfx and $pfxPass is the .pfx's password.

```
function Import-PfxCertificate {
param([string] $certPath, [string]$pfxPass)

$pfx = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$pfx.Import([string]$certPath, [string]$pfxPass, "Exportable,PersistKeySet")

$store = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store("My", "LocalMachine")
$store.open("MaxAllowed")
$store.add($pfx)
$store.close()
}
```

Comment: I think that you will have to run this code *as* the user you want to add the certs under. So the next question is, do you have the user's credentials or not?

Comment: If you look at the definition for that x509 certificate class you'll see there isn't even an enumeration to support anything besides current user and Local Computer. I believe the only way to accomplish this would be to impersonate the other user -- or in powershell a far easier way is to just create a new-pssession with their credentials, but it will require the username/password (in either scenario) to load their session

Comment: Briantist/Bill - Yes, I have the credentials and I understand how to pass the credentials properly. I also understand I would need to change the "LocalMachine" to "CurrentUser" which is simple enough. 

However, if either of you could maybe help with an example of taking the script above and having it run under a new PSSession or by using Start-Job with ScriptBlock that would be helpful. I have tried getting Start-Job with ScriptBlock to work a couple days ago but I kept getting different error messages about invalid arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have the credentials, I would start use `Start-Job` to do it. You can use the `-Credential` parameter to control what user the job runs as.

```powershell
$cred = Get-Credential

$scriptBlock = [ScriptBlock]::Create((Get-Item Function:\Import-PfxCertificate).Definition)

$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -ArgumentList $path,$password -Credential $cred
$job | Wait-Job 
$job | Receive-Job # if you want the output
$job | Remove-Job
```

Since you've already defined a function that does what you want, I'm creating a script block out of the function and using that for `Start-Job`. `-ArgumentList` is how you pass the parameters for the PFX path and the PFX password. I'm using `Get-Credential` to prompt you for the runas user, but you can provide the credential object however you want.

I think the easiest way is to run something like this:

```powershell
Get-Credential | Export-Clixml -Path C:\path\to\credentials.xml
```

This will store the credential object in a way that is encrypted, and can only be decrypted by the same user on the same computer that encrypted it. To read it back in:

```powershell
$cred = Import-Clixml -Path C:\path\to\credentials.xml
```

Back to the other code snippet, `Wait-Job` waits for it to finish. `Receive-Job` is optional, in case you're returning anything useful from your function.

`Remove-Job` removes it from the job list (otherwise it sticks around, which you can see with `Get-Job`).

Comment: I used your technique to get the serial number from a cert in another user's personal store. Worked great, thanks!