# Automate PowerShell from C# under a different user

Tags: c#, powershell, impersonation

I am trying to launch a local instance of PowerShell from C# under different user credentials - and then continue to invoke commands from C#. Is this possible?

If I launch PowerShell directly (not using runspaces) like so:

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create()
```

This doesn't seem to run PS out of process. Thus, it being run under the same credentials as my C# app. If I try to have this code run under impersonation, it actually throws an exception (even though old posts claim you can do so).

If I try to create an out of process Runspace like so:

```
RunspaceFactory.CreateOutOfProcessRunspace()
```

there is no way to pass in credentials that I can find.

I know that I can run PS under different credentials and execute script by sending a "Start-Process" command, but then I lose programmatic interactivity with C#. I don't see the results of the script invoke.

It seems that the only way to run PS from C# under a different user by prescribed methods is by using remote runspaces, except specifying the URI as localhost:

```
PSCredential creds = new PSCredential(UserName, GetSecurePassword(Password));

Uri RemoteComputerUri = Uri ?? new Uri($"{Scheme}://{ComputerName}:{Port}/wsman");
WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(RemoteComputerUri, Schema, creds);

using (Runspace remoteRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo))
{
      remoteRunspace.Open();
      PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
      ...
}
```

But, I don't want to require WSMan / HTTP configuration that remote runspaces requires. I just want to run PS out of process with different credentials but still be able to interact with it via C#.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using [start-job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28283753/import-pfx-certificate-into-separate-currentuser-personal-store-powershell/28335660#comment103478535_28335660) instead? I used this technique to [get serial the number](https://github.com/mossrich/PowershellRecipes/blob/master/CertificateFunctions.ps1) from a cert in another user's store. Disclaimer: I have not tried accessing PS output from C#.

Comment: Thanks, but it's the same issue. If I use PS commands within a PS session to spawn another process, I lose programmatic ability from within my C# app - which is key in my use case. I think the only solution is to really be able to launch a local Runspace under difference credentials from C# - but I don't know if that's possible / how to do it.